# NameError within class definition

Tags: python, nameerror

I wanted to define a class as follows:

```py
class ConfigManager:
    @classmethod
    def load_config(cls):
        # do some complex stuff to load something
        return config

    __CONFIG = ConfigManager.load_config()

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls):
        return cls.__CONFIG
```

And then when I run the following code, it reports a `NameError`:

```py
x = ConfigManager.get_config()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class ConfigManager:
  File "test.py", line 7, in ConfigManager
    __CONFIG = ConfigManager.load_config()
NameError: name 'ConfigManager' is not defined
```

Why does this error occur? Is it because Python code is executed by interpretation and when it goes to line 7, `class ConfigManager` is not yet finished to be defined?

Comment: Yes, that is why.

Comment: probably you want `@staticmethod`

Comment: @OlvinRoght `@staticmethod` does not work, since it still requires `class ConfigManager` to be completely defined at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class object only exists by its name *after* the class body and all class decorators are evaluated. What that means is that you cannot use the name `ConfigManager` inside the `ConfigManager` body itself. This *also* includes any function or method you call before the class is completed.

While building the class body, you can refer to names previously defined in the class body and names previously defined outside of the class body.

```
external_name = 'External'

class Demo:
    internal_name = 'Internal'
    print('Body see', external_name, internal_name)
    # throws an error
    print('Body does not see', late_internal_name, late_external_name)
    late_internal_name = 'LateInternal'

late_external_name = 'LateExternal'
```

This means you can define a function to load your configuration *as long as it does not need the class object*. Note that even when defined inside the class, this is not a (class-) method by the time you access it.

```
class ConfigManager:
    # not a method - does not receive cls/self
    def load_config():
        # do some complex stuff to load something
        return {}

    # call helper as a regular function
    __CONFIG = load_config()
    # clean up helper since it is not a proper method
    del load_config

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls):
        return cls.__CONFIG
```

Alternatively, you can lazily load the config if needed.

```
class ConfigManager:
    _CONFIG = None

    @classmethod
    def _load_config(cls):
        # do some complex stuff to load something
        return {}

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls):
        if cls._CONFIG is None:
            cls._CONFIG = cls._load_config()
        return cls._CONFIG
```

Comment: But I wonder if this is a particular feature of Python language or is it related to Python implementations?

Comment: This is part of the Python language - other implementations share this behaviour. Classes are evaluated, not defined. That means the class does not exist before it is completely evaluated.